# How can I make this simple script to run in multiple cores?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have implemented a code which reads files in directory and learn a model for every file.
My data and files are huge and it takes lot's of time to run. I want to make it parrallel and run it on server, but I don't have any idea and experience about how to parallelize it

would someone help me to parallelize it ?

Here is the part of the code that I want to make it parallele :

```
max.run<-10000
for (filename in dir(mydirectory))
{
    # Loading data

    filename = paste(data.dir,filename,sep="/")
    dfr=read.table(filename,header=TRUE)

    if (ncol(dfr) > 1)
    {
    y <- as.matrix(dfr[1])
        x <- as.matrix(dfr[2:ncol(dfr)])
        groupii <- c()
    groupiicoeffs <- c()

        while (TRUE) {


        if (ncol(x) == 0) {
        break
        }

        # Doing the Lasso regression

            M <- lars(x,y,type="lasso",normalize=TRUE,intercept=TRUE,use.Gram=TRUE)
        #exit()

        # If the Cp can not be calculated, only selecting the x most correlated with y 

        if (is.nan(M$Cp[1])) {
.
.
.
.
.


run <- run + 1
 if (run >= max.run) {

        break
        }
        }

.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Have a look at the foreach package using dopar to run in parallel: works on LINUX and Windows machines/clusters. There are some excellent threads on SO about this topic, you will find the answers you need to get started.

Comment: First replace your for loop with lappy. Then have a look at the parallel package (shipped with R)

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare some packages to start parallel work.

```
install.packages("foreach")
install.packages("parallel")
install.packages("doParallel")
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
```

After that follow my code.

```
max.run<-10000
n.cores = parallel::detectCores() -1 # Set number of cores you want (less than full core)
# In this code i will assume n.cores = 3
myCluster = parallel::makeCluster(n.cores) # This work start n.cores(3) new session 
# You can think myCluster as main name of our cluster.
doParallel::registerDoParallel(myCluster) # This is initiation for foreach statement
```

In parallel process, it is important to set where to make it parallel point. In this program, I think you have to make it parallele on 'for' statement as below

## Edited code

```
foreach::foreach(filename = dir(mydirectory),
                .packages = c("put packages you needed"),
                .combine = rbind 
# <- above '.combine' makes your result binded that produced by each foreach statement
) %dopar% {  
# Loading data

filename = paste(data.dir,filename,sep="/")
dfr=read.table(filename,header=TRUE)

if (ncol(dfr) > 1)
{
 y <- as.matrix(dfr[1])
 x <- as.matrix(dfr[2:ncol(dfr)])
 groupii <- c()
 groupiicoeffs <- c()

 while (TRUE) {


  if (ncol(x) == 0) {
    break
  }

  # Doing the Lasso regression

  M <- lars(x,y,type="lasso",normalize=TRUE,intercept=TRUE,use.Gram=TRUE)
  #exit()

  # If the Cp can not be calculated, only selecting the x most correlated with y 

  if (is.nan(M$Cp[1])) {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    result # I think here is a result part point ***
    # i will comment below detail about result 

    run <- run + 1
    if (run >= max.run) {

      break
    }
  }

  .
  .
  .
  .
}
}


}
```

### About result

In foreach statement, printed result will be binded. To help understand, i will show you simple example.

```
foreach(i=1:3,
.combine = rbind) %dopar% {
result = i
result #<- If it is not in foreach statement, result will be shown in console
}
```

And the output is

```
         [,1]
result.1    1
result.2    2
result.3    3
```

If you have question, feel free to ask.